# Python concurrent query performance using urllib2

Tags: python, linux, performance, urllib2

I wrote a Python script to grab contents (json) from a web service with 2500 different parameter permutations concurrently with 4 threads. The web service responses very quick and stable. On my test machine (Windows 7 x64, 4 Core, Python 2.7.8), it takes 10-15 seconds to grab all results.

But when I deploy the script onto x64 Debian 6 or on a CentOS 6.5 virtual machine, it takes more than 10 minutes to grab the same results. It really shocks me. Both VM are from the same network, which means the network latency should be the same. VM has also 4 cores allocated. IMHO, the hardware are almost the same.

```
from concurrent import futures
import urllib2

def parallel_query(urls):
    results = {}
    with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
        tasks = dict((executor.submit(query_html, url), url) for url in urls)
        for task in futures.as_completed(tasks):
            results[tasks[task]] = task.result()
    print results

def query_html(url):
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    return response.read()

parallel_query(
    ('http://api.server/?par1', # Here I only create 3 api calls. Actually
     'http://api.server/?par2', # in my real test, there are 2500 api calls
     'http://api.server/?par3') # to be generated
)
```

Both VMs have Python 2.6.6 installed. I tried to install Python 2.7.8 and Python 3.4.1, but the results are the same. There is no radical improvements at all. Is there any known performance issue on Linux?

Comment: Network latency can be worse for virtual machines compared to real ones because every packet has to move through two kernels before it gets to the network card. A factor 60 is extreme, though.

Comment: @larsmans I've setup a Win7 VM with the same hardware configuration. It takes 17 seconds. It is 2 seconds slower than physical environment, but still very much faster than Linux VM behaviors. I read https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/eglibc/+bug/417757/comments/7 and disabled ipv6 in Debian 6. Now it takes 6 minutes (previously was 12 minutes) I think dns resolving is a factor. But there is still something unknown to be explored.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks pretty good to me.  I've added a "statistics" section, and upped the number of concurrent threads to 2*num_cpus+1, which is a standard heuristic.

Results are from my Linux Mint Petra lappytop, hitting a standard Nginx webserver.

### source

```
import multiprocessing, time
from concurrent import futures
import urllib2

NUM_WORKERS = multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2 + 1
NUM_QUERIES = 25

def parallel_query(urls, nworkers):
    results = {}
    with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=nworkers) as executor:
        tasks = dict(
            (executor.submit(query_html, url), url) 
            for url in urls
        )
        for task in futures.as_completed(tasks):
            results[tasks[task]] = task.result()
    return results

def query_html(url):
    start = time.time()
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    _ = response.read()
    return time.time() - start

res = parallel_query(
    ('http://localhost/?num={}'.format(num)
     for num in range(NUM_QUERIES)
     ),
    nworkers = NUM_WORKERS,
)
timing = res.values()

print 'STATS:'
total = sum(timing)
print 'min\t{:.3}'.format( min(timing) )
print 'max\t{:.3}'.format( max(timing) )
print 'avg\t{:.3}'.format( total / len(timing) )
```

### output

```
STATS:
min 0.000849
max 0.00253
avg 0.00134
```